# Linux: Find out /dev description for a device

Tags: linux, dev

I have a microphone that I connected via USB. When I do dmesg it shows

```
[37830.040274] usb 5-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 4
```

How do I find out what /dev/??? identifier has been associated with the device? I want to record something using XVidCap and need to set the microphone for it to work.

PS: I'm on Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: Please migrate to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always output `ls /dev > devs.txt` then connect your device, do it again `ls /dev > devs2.txt` then run a `diff devs.txt devs2.txt` and see what shows up.

Comment: Hmm.. I really like the idea. Very smart. Unfortunately they seem to be identical.

Comment: try `find /dev` instead - there are subdirectories. USB is in a subdirectory on one of the machines i use.

Answer (score 1):

Could be worth poking around in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/5-1/`, but i can't immediately find a way to get from there to the name in `/dev`.

Answer (score 1):

> #lsblk

Sample Output:

```
sda      8:0    1   7.3G  0 disk
ââsda1   8:1    1   243M  0 part
ââsda2   8:2    1     1K  0 part
ââsda5   8:5    1     7G  0 part /
sdd      8:48   0   1.8T  0 disk
ââsdd1   8:49   0   1.8T  0 part
```

Answer (score 0):

It is usually set up as `/dev/dsp1` what do you see in yours?
Also see if `lsusb --verbose | less` yields you any useful output.
More detailed output may be present in /var/log/messages when you attached the USB device and  your computer identified it.

Comment: That's an old OSS name and isn't relevant on a modern system with ALSA sound.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Anderson already mentioned, the information is available in /sys. There's 
/sys/bus/usb/devices//product
/sys/bus/usb/devices//manufacturer

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I see the device in /sys/bus/usb/devices/5-1. Where can I obtain the /dev/ identifier from there? There is a file dev that has the number 189:516. Does this somehow help?

Answer (score 0):

If linux has recognised it and is able to handle it then any devices would be under `/dev/snd` but you don't really want to be accessing the device directly on an ALSA based system.

Instead you should use the ALSA libaries and/or command line tools to access the device.